# Multiple clipping regions in canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to clip multiple regions of an image,
so I have a custom class extending `ImageView`

This is my onDraw:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.clipRect(rect1);
        canvas.clipRect(rect2);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

When I clip 1 rectangle it works fine, but when I have multiple it doesn't show anything at all.

**UPDATE:**

I also tried clipping using Path instead:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.clipPath(path1);
    canvas.clipPath(path2);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

But none works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, which is using:

```
canvas.clipPath(Path path, Op op);
```

instead of:

```
canvas.clipPath(Path path);
```

With extra clips, and this also works with `Rect` and `Region`.

This how my code looks like:

```
Path path1 = new Path();

private void init(){

    path1.moveTo(100, 100);
    path1.lineTo(100, 500);
    path1.lineTo(500, 500);
    path1.lineTo(500, 100);
    path1.close();

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.clipPath(path1);
    canvas.clipPath(path2, Region.Op.UNION);
    canvas.clipPath(path3, Region.Op.UNION);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

}
```

Comment: Region.Op.UNION is no longer supported for clipPath in Android P.

Answer (score 0):

It will be intersecting or replaced in your rects.

Try using clipPath(...) instead.

ie.

```
Path p1 = ...;
Path p2 = ...;
p2.addPath(p1);
canvas.clipRect(p2);
```

If for some reason clipPath does not work, then build a region and use clipRegion.

Edit:

As per OPs final solution, it is also possible to merge the regions at the time of adding the clip region:

```
canvas.clip{whatever}(rect/region/path, op).
```

Comment: Then you probably need to show what you tried, because it's the solution

Comment: I'd suggest showing what you have tried, including clipPath and clipRegion

Comment: As per your amended example, you CAN'T DO TWO PATHS....merge them into one path (or region) first. Same problem as two rects.

Bottom line: make one big path/regions, can .clipX ONCE.

See amended answer for example.

Comment: I tried a different approach, and it works now I can clip as many paths and rects as I want, check my answer. Thank you !

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you: merging the regions one way or another is the key.